# Elements are not aligned properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create a navbar. 2 problems here.

1. Search text bar's width is not 100% It should fill the width to 100% of its column.
2. Glyphicons's are not vertically aligned.

Here [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nerzid/53wp961v/1/)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```css
html {
  background-color: #F4F5F9
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group input-group-md">
            <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="margin-top: 0px;"></span></span>
            <input class="form-control left-border-none" placeholder="Search things..." type="text" name="search_text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size: 21px; margin-top: 0px;"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="font-size: 21px;margin-top: 0px;"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size: 21px;margin-top: 0px;"></span></a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

```
.navbar-default .container {
  display: flex;
}
.navbar-default .container [class^="col-"]:first-child, 
.navbar-default .container [class^="col-"]:last-child {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I'd ask why you used `col-*-*` in the first place here, since you seem to want their default behavior overridden.
Besides, you should always use `col-*-*` as direct children of `.row`s.

---

**2.**

```
.navbar-left .glyphicon {
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

---

Working example:

```css
html {
  background-color: #F4F5F9
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-default .container {
  display: flex;
}
.navbar-default .container [class^="col-"]:first-child, 
.navbar-default .container [class^="col-"]:last-child {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-left .glyphicon {
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group input-group-md">
            <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="margin-top: 0px;"></span></span>
            <input class="form-control left-border-none" placeholder="Search things..." type="text" name="search_text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size: 21px; margin-top: 0px;"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="font-size: 21px;margin-top: 0px;"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size: 21px;margin-top: 0px;"></span></a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

Always [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) your `CSS` before deploying. For maximum browser compatibility, use `> 0%` in settings (small box at the bottom).

**Side note:** always load `jquery(.min).js` before `bootstrap(.min).js`.

Comment: Thank you! . Im pretty new to bootstrap and css stuff so can I ask another question, why did you say the thing about "col-*-*" ? I though they were about giving desired spaces to contents. For example, I want my search textbox to be twice as big as the right content. Is what i did is wrong for that ?

Comment: If that's what you want, you were correct in giving them `col-xs-8` and `col-xs-4` (the rest are not necesary), but I must have misunderstood your question. What exactly did you mean by **1.**? You wanted the contents not to have padding? Could you please clarify? I'll update the answer when it's clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want [this](http://imgur.com/a/L9dnJ) to look like [this](http://imgur.com/a/XGRFn)

Comment: Actually, what you've done is perfect for small screens, but for desktops, It looks bad. By the way, thank you for helping me.

Comment: [`Here it is`](https://jsfiddle.net/ksnp2u6c/2/). Note I have put the `col-*-*` inside a `.row` (like I advised in the answer) and I also removed some markup. If you want to limit behavior on certain widths, just wrap it inside the desired media query `@media (min-width: 768px) {}` or `@media (max-width: 767px) {}`, etc...